# How to use google cloud natural language api using python?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, google-cloud-language

When I run code for google cloud natural language using python on local system , code is execute successfully , but When I run the same code on some network restrictions(may be office network), it show me error. I already created google service account and enabled google cloud language API.

Error:
Contiue show like this
E0430 10:49:06.368000000 7700 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1504] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.

Code :

```
from google.cloud import language_v1
client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient.from_service_account_json("json file path")
text = "Hello, world!"
document = language_v1.Document(content=text, type_=language_v1.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(request={"document": document}).document_sentiment
print("Text: {}".format(text))
print("Sentiment: {}, {}".format(sentiment.score, sentiment.magnitude))
```

When I force to stop execution it show like this error message :

sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(request={"document": document}).document_sentiment
File "google_sentiment_analysis\sent_venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\language_v1\services\language_service\client.py", line 477, in analyze_sentiment
response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
File "google_sentiment_analysis\sent_venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 154, in **call**
return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "google_sentiment_analysis\sent_venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
return retry_target(
File "google_sentiment_analysis\sent_venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 205, in retry_target
raise exceptions.RetryError(
google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling target function, last exception: 503 failed to connect to all addresses

Please tell me what type of permission is required in google cloud or anything else?
Thanks.

Comment: At what line do you get this error?

Comment: 5th line  show me error.

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo. This:

```
client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient.from_service_account_json("json file path")
```

Should be this:

```
client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient().from_service_account_json("json file path")
```

Comment: Error in 5th line : Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started